# Django admin inline calculated field won't save

Tags: django, field, admin, inline

One of the fields in my inline needs to be calculated. I overrode the BaseInLineFormSet clean method and can do the calculation there and apparently set the field's value there but it doesn't get saved to the DB, and consequently is also not displayed. The field defaults to zero, btw, in case that matters. Here's a hard-coded version:

```
class EmployeeAssignmentInLineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(EmployeeAssignmentInLineFormSet, self).clean()
        self.cleaned_data[0]['cost'] = 5000
```

I also tried overriding save_formset in the ModelAdmin - same result:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    formset.cleaned_data[0]['cost'] = 5000
    formset.save()
```

When I set the value just in clean I can see it's been set when it gets to save_formset, but it still ends up being zero in the DB. Am I in the wrong place or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be much interest in this but for the sake of completeness, this is what I ended up doing. All my gazillion attempts at trying to save the field when the record is saved failed. Simply putting something into cleaned_data doesn't work. I tried overriding clean, save_model, save_related, save_formset - no joy. So now I'm in the Inline options:

```
readonly_fields = ('get_cost', )
fields = ('project', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'effort', 'role', 'get_cost')

def get_cost(self, obj):
    if obj.effort and obj.cost == 0.0:
        obj.cost = obj.employee._calculate_cost(obj.effort)
        obj.save()
    return obj.cost
get_cost.short_description = 'Cost'
```

Need the conditional of course to avoid saving the cost every time the inline formset is loaded. Seems odd to save the field *after* the rest of the record has been saved, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a ModelFormSet has a `cleaned_data` attribute like that
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L623

I'm not sure why you're not getting an exception from your code above in that case, but it looks to me like you should try instead:

```
def clean(self):
    super(EmployeeAssignmentInLineFormSet, self).clean()
    self.forms[0].cleaned_data['cost'] = 5000
```

Comment: Well I don't know what happened in my previous comment so just disregard it and I'll try again. If I put a breakpoint at my line (self.cleaned_data[0]['cost'] = 5000) I see that value and the value at self.forms[0].cleaned_data['cost'] are both zero. Then I step and check the values again and both are 5000. So they both refer to the same thing and then naturally I still get 0 in the DB.