# Django modeladmin fields - display/edit values in MHz, save to database in Hz?

Tags: django

I would like to change an existing django modeladmin view that currently has a field 'frequency_hz' so that users can view the current values in MHz and enter new values in MHz, and have modeladmin convert the value back to Hz when saving to the database.

Is there a simple way to do this with modelAdmin - or is there any other suggested way to achieve what I am looking for?

So far it looks like modelAdmin has limited capabilities with regards to any sort of calculation performed on a field:

- I can add a property to my model with the calculated value (frequency_MHz), and add this property to list_display, but it is not editable. It doesn't look like there's a way to enable modelAdmin to treat these calculated properties as writable fields (understandably)
- [I see with modelInlines I can define a submethod that returns the expected value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211310/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-admin-inline)  - however I can't get this to work with modelAdmin - and I believe this suffers a similar limitation to being read only.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways.

1. Your model is defaulted as  as MHz, but then the `save` method calculates the correct database value in Hz for you.
2. You define a new `forms.ModelForm` with a `frequency_MHz` field on it, set `form = MyCustomFormWithMHz` and in the `save_model` method on the model admin you convert the value from that field to use in the model save.

Comment: It's strange, I'm trying to add a new custom field to a new form to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get modelAdmin to recognize the field I have added. I add it to the form as a DecimalField (frequency_mhz = models.DecimalField()). If I try to use this field in the field list for the form, or the field list or field sets in the admin I display it with, Django throws the error 'django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (frequency_mhz) specified for BaseBand'

Comment: You'll have to update your question with some code ...